# SEAndroid in 4.4

Tags: android, selinux

i found this statement in: "http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/se-linux.html"

In Android 4.3, SELinux was fully permissive. In Android 4.4, SELinux was made enforcing for the domains for several root processes: installd, netd, vold and zygote. All other processes, including other services and all apps, remain in permissive mode to allow further evaluation and prevent failures in Android 4.4. Still, an errant application could trigger an action in a root process that is not allowed, thereby causing the process or the application to crash.

which mean that SEAndroid is not fully enabled yet, can anyone confirm this please?

Answer (score 1):

SE for Android has three main modes: disabled, permissive and enforcing.  In 4.3 the default mode is permissive.  This means that SE is enabled, but policy violations are only logged, not enforced.  In permissive mode, everything works the same as if SE was not present or disabled, except that you can look at the denial log and see how the policy is working and what it's effect might be in enforcing mode.

For 4.4, the default mode was changed to enforcing, but the default policy was kept very simple and only placed protections around a few key root processes.

So the answer is yes, SE for Android is fully enabled and enforcing in 4.4.  However, the default policy is very loose. If you want to confirm the mode on a particular device, you can use `adb shell getenforce`.  If you have root, you can also use `setenforce` as follows (1=Enforcing, 0=Permissive):

```
usage:  setenforce [ Enforcing | Permissive | 1 | 0 ]
```

Finally, if you're interested in taking a look at the actual policy on a device, use `adb pull /sepolicy` to bring down the policy binary, and then use [apol](http://oss.tresys.com/projects/setools) to view it.  On Ubuntu, `apol` is part of package `setools-gui`.